# Intermittent loud engine at 3k RMP under load

Tags: noise, mazda, miata

Car: 1991 NA Miata / MX5 1.6L

I have a very strange problem where the engine volume triples between 2800-3100 RMP underload. However, this problem is intermittent. I can tell when the car starts if it's going to be loud or quiet. It does not matter if the car just started or is warmed up, the loudness at that range will still be tripled.

Things that I have tried to remedy the problem:

- Check for exhaust leaks
- Try different exhaust systems (6 total configurations)
- Changed engine oil
- Changed transmission oil
- Changed diff oil
- Changed spark plugs
- Italian tune-up
- Replaced ripped roof
- Installed dynamat

Nothing seemed to remedy the problem

Comment: I'm not sure about the 91, but later 90's versions of the MX5 had a dual inlet intake at the head. There was a butterfly which opened to allow more air to flow into the cylinder at a certain rpm. This was "sort of" the forerunner to the variable valve timing, I guess. If yours has this, it might be malfunctioning. I believe it doesn't come into play until around 4k on the engines which have it.

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 That's a good suggestion however I do not believe my car came equipped with one